# How can I select a div in second level?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="class" style="cursor: pointer">
    <label id="cost">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cost)</label>
    <div class="no" hidden="hidden">
        <input type="text" id='@item.PriceId' class="text" style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)" value='@item.Cost.ToString()' />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this html code.And I want this jquery code:

```
    $(".text").live("keypress",function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON('/Price/AjaxPriceEdit', { id: $(this).attr("id"), cost: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            });
            $(this).hide();
            //Here I want to show #cost
        }
    });
```

Now I want to select #cost that is in the div#class.How can I select it in the marked place?

Answer (score 1):

To just select it:

```
$('#class #cost')
```

As others have pointed out, `$('#cost')` should be enough, as ids are supposed to be unique on the page. However, if your script is in an external file that can be included in several pages, this nesting of `#id` selectors allows to target exactly this div on the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using IDs, it should be unique on the WHOLE page. 
So, `#cost` shouldn't be present anywhere on the same page.

Otherwise, you should make it a `class`, in which case, you can use `$("#class .cost");`

If you are still going to use the ID itself, you just have to use `$("#cost")`.

Comment: Yes all of my labels have same id and exactly because of this I want to select the label that is in the #class which the current textbox is in it too.If I change the id to class it will work but just for the first time.In other words I want to select the div#class that is the parent of the parent of my button.How can I do this?

Comment: @HamidReza no, then you shouldn't be using IDs, instead use `class`

Comment: @HamidReza whatever it is, ID should be unique, no matter on what element you are using it on.

Answer (score 1):

You can select it directly as it has an identifier:

```
$('#cost')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".text").live("keypress",function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON('/Price/AjaxPriceEdit', { id: $(this).attr("id"), cost: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            });
            $(this).hide();
            var cost = $('#class #cost').html();
            alert(cost); //This will display the actual cost value in an alert, do with it what you please!
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly access the element with id as id is unique, if you have repeated html blocks with same id, You can use [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the label which is sibling and do not need id.

```
alert($(this).prev('label').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select it like :

```
$(".text").live("keypress",function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON('/Price/AjaxPriceEdit', { id: $(this).attr("id"), cost: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            });
            $(this).hide();
           $('#cost').show(); // or whatever you want to do with it
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have `id` assigned to the target so:

```
$("#cost")
```

and these:

```
$('#class #cost')
$('#class').children('#cost')
$('#class').find('#cost')
```

and this way too:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('#cost')
```

Answer (score 0):

#cost is the previous node of the parent div

.parent will up to the parent node and .prev will select previous node

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).parent().prev().show();
```

and with keep chaining

```
$(this).hide().parent().prev().show();
```